# how to print pandas row with second sorted correponding row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, statistics

I am looking to do the simple task of neatly printing the `name` row, corresponding to country, and right of that the `islmtotal` row sorted in descending order. My code below only prints `islmtotal`, but I've given an example of how it should look:

```
Name Islmtotal


USA 1.99

GER 1.93

NED .76
```

---

```
religion = pd.read_csv('natldata.csv', usecols = [0, 2, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58], na_values=['NULL'])

religion['islmtotal']= religion[['islmsunpct', 'islmshipct', 'islmibdpct', 'islmnatpct', 'islmalwpct', 'islmahmpct', 'islmothrpct', 'islmgenpct']].sum(axis=1)

religyearask = input("Please enter year in multiples of 5 (eg 1980):  ")

maxstateyear = religion.loc[religion['year'] == religyearask].sort_values('year', ascending=False).groupby(['name'], sort=False)['islmtotal'].max()

print(maxstateyear.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: How does it print now? What does your original df look like? Not much info to go on here.

Comment: I've edited the code above for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to break up the steps, so you can pinpoint the source of your trouble.

First, create a mask to index.

```
m = religion['year'] == religyearask
```

Now, index and sort.

```
df = religion.loc[m].sort_values('year', ascending=False)
```

Now, `groupby` and find `max`.

```
df = df.groupby('name', as_index=False)['islmtotal'].max()
```

Presumably, this is the source of your trouble. Note that `groupby` by default converts the group-by column to index, so `as_index=False` will prevent this.

Now, convert to `to_string` and print.

```
print(maxstateyear.to_string(index=False))
```

---

**OneLiner™**

```
print(
    religion.loc[religion['year'] == religyearask]\
            .sort_values('year', ascending=False)\
            .groupby('name', as_index=False)['islmtotal'].max()\
            .to_string(index=False)
)
```

Comment: ok this has gotten me considerably closer, but what i'm seeing the above code show is the columns, however its group by alphabetized country. I would prefer descending numbers as the sorting method.

Comment: @Mr.Jibz Great to know. Unfortunately, I am not able to visualise your problem, if you just explain it to me. This is just your code with a minor modification. If you would like help on how to _change_ your method to get close to your solution, I'd recommend opening a new question and doing the following things; 1. show your data in text form, 2. show your current output. 3. show your expected output. 4. show your current code. Cheers!